# User privileges enumerating serial device

Tags: groups, permissions, serial

I'm trying to use the [Java Simple Serial Connector](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_examples) on Arch Linux. I have a simple program listed below:

```
import jssc._

object Main {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    println("Started")
    val portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames
    portNames.foreach(println(_))
  }
}
```

If I run `ls -la /dev/ttyACM0` I get the following:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 166, 0 May  5 18:41 /dev/ttyACM0
```

If I run `groups ryan` I get `uucp ryan`

If I run `sbt run` I get just the line `Started`

If I run `sudo sbt run` I get the following:

```
Started
/dev/ttyACM0
```

I've added my user `ryan` to the `uucp` group, which owns `/dev/ttyACM0`, the device I'm trying to communicate with. What else could be preventing my program from enumerating the device?

Comment: Did you log out and log back in (needed for group changes to take effect) ?

Comment: ...nope, forgot to do that! If you repost as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: Did that actually fix it ?

Comment: Yes, worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to log out and log back in after adding yourself to the `uucp` group, which is necessary for group changes to take effect.

Here's an [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups) about permissions and groups on the Archlinux wiki, in case you need more info.